# Localizing iphone app html files and strange xcode 4.2 warnings

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization

I've got an App that I am trying to localize for several languages. I'm doing most of the localization through .strings files, but for the larger help files, I need localized versions of html files.

I've read Apple's documentation as well as doing many searches on Google, and I think I am doing things correctly.

In my xcode project directory, I have an "en.lproj" and a "ja.lproj" (Japanese). I put versions of my HTML help file in each directory, and I import these into my Resources group in xcode. After doing so, the files seem to show up correctly. I see a "help.html" file under Resources, and it is a "group" and if I look inside it I see:

help.html (english)
help.html (japanese)

When I build my App, my App seems to correctly contain the two versions of the files under their appropriate .lproj directories, and everything is working correctly when I run the App (I see English documentation when settings are English, and Japanese when settings are Japanese).

However, when I build my project, I get annoying warnings from xcode 4.2:

Warning: Multiple build commands for output file  .../ja.lproj/StartQuizController.html
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file  .../en.lproj/StartQuizController.html

From what I understand, these "multiple build command" messages occur when there are conflicting filenames that are being added to your App. However, since these files are localized and exist in their own subdirectories, there is no real conflict.

Am I doing something wrong, or are the warnings a bug in xcode 4.2?

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Have the same problem, seems like Xcode's defect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can prevent these warnings if you do it the Xcode way.

Xcode uses only one copy command to copy the localized files, you have probably two separate commands.

You could try to delete the files form the "copy bundle resources" build phase first.
Delete the copy command for the localized files and add a new one. If Xcode treats your localized files right it should show a single file instead of a file for each localization in the "Choose items to add"-Picker.

---

If that doesn't work just remove them completely and add the physical files again.
Backup all your html files. Then delete them from the project (both logical and physical).

- Add the English version of the file to Xcode, let Xcode copy it to your directory.
- Select file in left sidebar
- Open first tab of the right sidebar
- add localizations by using the + button in the localization section
- either replace the content of the file trough Xcode or use Finder to replace the localized versions.

Comment: This worked perfect! Thanks for the tip! As you suggested, I had done the same thing manually and something in XCode's database must have been missing.

Answer (score 1):

I´m trying to localize my project as well. I always add a in-App user´s manual in a html file wich gets loaded on a UIWebView.

I haven´t done it yet, but what I´m going to do is to create different files for each language, say for example:

```
info_en.html // for english
info_es.html // for spanish
info_ca.html // for catalan
```

then when the webView gets loaded, instead of loading the `@"info_en.html"` file, I will load the `NSLocalizedString(@"info", nil);` Then, in each localized string file, the name for the html file will match the language.

I believe this should help but, again, I haven´t tried myself yet.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! This sounds like it would work, although @fluchtpunkt's approach is more consistent with how I had been doing things.